# Reload div without refreshing main page

Tags: jquery, html

first thanks for your time. I've done some research and found many useful similar questions as mine. But I still can't make this work, I have a simple form that I want to refresh when submiting, here is what I tried

Here is my form:

```html
<div id="contact" class="contact">
  <div class="container">
<?php if(!empty($emailSent)): ?>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="alert alert-success text-center">Votre message a ete envoye avec succes.</div>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
<?php if(!empty($hasError)): ?>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-4">
      <div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Un erreur s'est produite, essayer a nouveau.</div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
        <input type="text"  name="form-name" placeholder="Nom" />
        <input type="email"  name="form-email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="text" name="form-subject" placeholder="Objet" />
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <textarea  rows="3"  name="form-message" placeholder="Message" /></textarea>
        <div class="sub">
          <button id="envoyer" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Envoyer</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is my jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#envoyer").click(function(evt) {
     $("#contact").load("index.php")
     evt.preventDefault();
  })
})
</script>
```

Once again thanks for your precious time !

Comment: Do you want to load something else instead of the form on click or do you want to send the form data post to server and reload the form?

Comment: Yes ! I want to load one of both "if(!empty($emailSent))" or " if(!empty($hasError))" in function of what have been sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use an iframe with your form, you should use ajax to post the form data to server and load the fail or success message from the server, without refreshing the page.

To post data to the server use this jquery function (explained and written below):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  dataType: dataType,
  success: successFunction,
  error: errorFunction
});
```

The API: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
AJAX can send a request to the server and receive data without refreshing the whole page, you can use to update your html at the client. I made a picture for you:

[image: AJAX request and response]

So let's begin:

In your form you only use html and javascript:

```
<div id="contact" class="contact">
  <div class="container">

    <!-- here will appear after sending your form data -->
    <!-- the answer with fail or success message -->
    <span id="serverAnswer"></span>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <form action="urlToFormSubmitPage.php" id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
        <input type="text"  name="form-name" placeholder="Nom" />
        <input type="email"  name="form-email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="text" name="form-subject" placeholder="Objet" />
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <textarea  rows="3"  name="form-message" placeholder="Message" /></textarea>
        <div class="sub">
          <button id="envoyer" class="btn btn-default">Envoyer</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On the server side you've got an php skript or something else that receives and saves the form data and generates the answer, for example:

```
//read in the data with PHP and $_POST[...]

//Do something with your data, for example save to database

//echo fail or success
<?php if(!empty($emailSent)): ?>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="alert alert-success text-center">Votre message a ete envoye avec succes.</div>
    </div>
<?php else: ?>
<?php if(!empty($hasError)): ?>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-4">
      <div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Un erreur s'est produite, essayer a nouveau.</div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now write the ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  ...
```

...read in your form data and the url from your form with something like that (the url in your form html element action attribute should point to your php page):

```
  ...
  url: $('#contact-form').attr( 'action' ),
  data: $('#contact-form').serialize(),
  ...
```

...you expects html from the php page:

```
  ...
  dataType: 'html',
  ...
```

...and your jquery ajax funtion should have a successFunction (which is called on server answer) like this:

```
   ...
   success: function(data) {
       //set your received html message from php page to your server answer html element
       $('#serverAnswer').html(data);
   },
   error: function() {
       alert("something went wrong while sending data to server");
   }
});
```

ajax function is ready,
now trigger the ajax with your click function, you've already written:

```
$(function() {
  $("#envoyer").click(function(evt) {
     $.ajax({
        ...
     });
     evt.preventDefault();
  })
});
```

That isn't a full solution, i can't write the whole code for you, but i hope, that this small tutorial could help you, to solve your problem.

If you want to check, whether your posted data are send to the right url or the answer is correct or something else, use the browser development tools: Press `F12` and under network tab you will find some information, that can help you to debug your ajax message.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I hope your answer will help more people than only me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **javascript** `location.reload()`

like this:

```
<button id="envoyer" onclick="location.reload()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Envoyer</button>
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cbtqwr5n/